# Bigquery: Will switching from BQ sandbox to BQ paid will change 60 days data limit setup in sandbox

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

Bigquery: Will switching from BQ sandbox to BQ paid will change 60 days data limit setup in sandbox.
Also, will I be able to export all GA4 data (last 1 year minimum) post switching to BQ paid?

currently we only have 60 days data in BQ sandbox and want to know if moving to BQ paid service will remove this limitation.
lso, will I be able to export all GA4 data (last 1 year minimum) post switching to BQ paid?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the change from 60 days is automatic, you may have to change it manually.

Unfortunately, you can't export old data from GA4. Once you are out of the sandbox and have changed the data limit, you will start to get more days stored.